# Is it possible to disable all mysql_connect(): Too many connections emails, but not other errors?

Tags: mysql

Right now I get about 4000 emails daily from this error as I run a DB backup that clogs up the DB for a few mins ant these emails are getting enormous.

Wondering if its possible to stop mysql from sending me emails about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that, disable your mailer on the script that checking for this error. Look for the script and comment out the mailer.

Answer (score 0):

4000 connections per day is *very* few.  4000 per *minute* is a lot.  So, something else is going wrong.

- Decrease `wait_timeout` to, say, 30 (seconds)
- Increase `max_connections` to, say, 200.
- Have your application disconnect after finishing its tasks.
- Decrease the parallelism in the client.  You need that to be less than `max_connections`.